# Change the Header text of particular column in gridview while the source code is written in .cs page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a web application using asp.net with c# and I have a small grid view whose code are shown below.

```
   if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "Journal")
        {
            SqlConnection con = new
      SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectConnectionString"].ToString());
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select p.Name,m.FID,m.Type,m.Date,m.Theme,m.Duration,m.Organizer,m.UpdateDate from WorkshopSC_det m INNER JOIN Personal_det p  ON m.FID= p.FID where m.updateDate  between @Start and @End order by m.updateDate desc ", con);
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Start", SqlDbType.Date).Value = startDate;
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@End", SqlDbType.Date).Value = endDate;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

In aspx

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None">
  <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333"></RowStyle>
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

The output of the grid view is shown as below.
[image: Gridview output]

Here you can see that the column named `organizer` is present,but now I have to change the column name as row,but in database the original name will be as `organizer` itself.
I have one solution i.e rename the column name in database as `Role` instead of `organizer`.But it will affect 5 to 6 pages in application which will take so much of time.Is there any other way to change the name?.Any help appreciated.

Comment: How you have given header name as of now? I am not seeing "organizer" column name in your select statement !

Comment: `SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select p.Name, m.FID,m.Title,m.Type,m.DOP,m.Type1,m.Type2,m.ImpactFactor,m.Volume,m.Coauthors,m.Authors,m.Publisher,m.URL,m.Role,m.UpdateDate from Journal_det m INNER JOIN Personal_det p  ON m.FID= p.FID where m.updateDate  between @Start and @End order by m.updateDate desc ", con);` It willl call the values from the table.

Comment: @ Shreyas I got it, but there is no "organizer" column in your select statement. Then how come its appearing in grid!!

Comment: @Naveen Now i edited the question,i think you will get it now.

Comment: @ Shreyas below is my answer. Hope it will help you or give some idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is to add an alias name to the column in select statement like below, keeping in mind that you are auto generating columns of grid.

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select p.Name,m.FID,m.Type,m.Date,m.Theme,m.Duration,m.Organizer as [NewName],m.UpdateDate from WorkshopSC_det m INNER JOIN Personal_det p  ON m.FID= p.FID where m.updateDate  between @Start and @End order by m.updateDate desc ", con);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.gvw1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "The new header";
}
```

Or

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "The new header";
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.